# how to determine which serverside Button click in Client Side javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to determine  which serverside Button click in Client Side javascript?
There are many Buttons in the form.

```
      function onMyClicked()
      {
        var btn = ??;
        if (btn == 'IDDelete') {
        var result = confirm("........ ");
        if (result){       
        xxxxx
        }
        else close();
        }
        else if(btn=='IDClose'){
        xxxxx
        }

         window.onunload = function (){
         onMyClicked();
   }

    <asp:Button ID="IDDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" --->
    <asp:Button ID="IDClose" runat="server" Text="Close" ---->
```

**EDIT:**

```
var isDirty;
        isDirty = 0;        
        function setDirty() {
            isDirty = 1;
        }        
        function onMyClicked() {
        var btn =???;
        if (btn == 'IDClose') {       
                var sSave;
                if (isDirty == 1) {            
                    sSave = window.returnValue = confirm('------');                    
                    if (window.returnValue == false) closerel();
                    if (sSave == true) {                    
                        document.getElementById('__EVENTTARGET').value = 'IDSave';
                        document.getElementById('__EVENTARGUMENT').value = 'Click';  
                        window.document.form1.submit();                        
                    }
                    else {                                 
                          close();                     
                    }
                }
                else close();
          }            
        }       
 window.onunload = function (){
         onMyClicked();
   }     

<asp:Button ID="IDDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" >
<asp:Button ID="IDClose" runat="server" Text="Close" >
<asp:Button ID="IDSave" runat="server" Text="Save" >
<asp:Button ID="IDClose" runat="server" Text="Close" >
```

How to determinde IDClose click?

Comment: I hope you understand your client event fire before server ones do?

Answer (score 1):

If you use OnClientClick property of the button, the function you type in the property runs. So your code will become:

```
function delete()
{
    var result = confirm("........ ");
    if (result){       
    xxxxx
    }
    else close();
    }
}

function close()
{
    xxxxx
}

<asp:Button ID="IDDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="Delete">
<asp:Button ID="IDClose" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClientClick="Close">
```